How to show that $1-\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{n}}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}<\dfrac{1}{4n}$
In the calculation of a problem, I need to show that $1-\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{n}}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}<\dfrac{1}{4n}$ holds for any positive integer $n$. I got the expansion of $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{n}}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}=1-\dfrac{1}{4n}+O(\dfrac{1}{n^2})$ from the Wolframalpha website as inthe picture, but how to know the error term is positive for all $n$?
expansion of the series

You could also separate into even case and odd case, in order to obtain algebraic expressions to work with

Gamma function at half integers have nice formulas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#Integers_and_half-integers.

WA gave more terms

@ClaudeLeibovici But still don't know why the remainder is positive

This is Stirling approximation

One observation is that this seems to be true for all real $n> 0$, not just positive integer $n$. (For $n<1/4$ this is trivial since $1-1/(4n)<0$.) So while a proof using even/odd $n$ may be possible it's not as general as it could be.

One way is to use $\ln \Gamma(x)$. Let $n$ be real. After rearranging the terms, take logarithm, and take derivative (digamma function). Use the bounds for digamma function to prove that the aforementioned expression is monotone.
